# How can I set default (global) options for helpers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I need to fix the problem with `body` element and the css `overflow` attribute discussed in this post:
[When a fancybox 2 is activated, a scrollbar flashes on the parent page causing the content to shift left and then back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924495/when-a-fancybox-2-is-activated-a-scrollbar-flashes-on-the-parent-page-causing-t)

Using the helper option `helpers: {overlay: {locked: false}}` fixes my problem, but I need a solution to set this option for all Fancybox calls, this way I do not need to spend this setting on each call.

I tried with different forms, but doesn't works:

```
$.fancybox.open([{
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
}]);

$.extend($.fn.fancybox.helpers, {
    overlay: {
        locked: false
    }
});

$.fn.fancybox.defaults.overlay.locked = false;
```

I do not want to change the css component, because currently use the same via Bower.

Comment: are you binding fancybox to different selectors?

Comment: @JFK Yes, for many different selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an object with this setting that you use in all of your fancyBox calls:

```
var fancyBoxDefaults = 
{
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
};
$(".fancybox1").fancybox(fancyBoxDefaults);
$(".fancybox2").fancybox(fancyBoxDefaults);
```

If you need to set settings for any specific fancyBox, you could extend the object:

```
$(".fancybox3").fancybox($.extend(fancyBoxDefaults,{
    maxWidth: 800,
    maxHeight: 600
}));
```