# HTML content only scrolls with scrollbar, not mouse wheel

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have a `<div>` on my page with a fixed height, and `overflow-y: scroll;` set so that the content will scroll when it passes the bottom edge of the `<div>`. Nothing out of the ordinary.

For some bizarre reason, the mouse wheel will only scroll the content if the cursor is over *empty space* in the `<div>` or if it's over the scrollbar itself. If the cursor happens to be over any of the text content in the `<div>`, the mouse wheel won't do anything.

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome, so it isn't just a quirk of a particular rendering engine or something.

The `<div>` in question is overlaid on top of another via `position: absolute;`, so I'm assuming that somehow the `<div>` behind it is interfering with the mouse wheel event - but then you'd think the problem would be reversed (the `<div>` would scroll *when* the cursor was over the text, not over the empty space).

Anyone else ever see anything like this before? I'm stumped!

Comment: Weird, could you post it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I am able to replicate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qNS3S/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it - it's because I was using the FancyBox [mousewheel plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565843/fancybox-how-to-scroll-page-when-fancybox-is-focused). This causes FancyBox to capture all mousewheel events (for use with scrolling through galleries). Since I'm not actually using any galleries, I have no need for it, so I took it out and immediately that fixed my problem.

Comment: in my case, two plugins were there - mousewheel plugin and smoothpagescroll