# Scrolling on webpage does not work

Tags: html, css, web, scroll

I have a website https://anglickyzarok.cz/ and somehow the scrolling does not work.

Is here anybody who can tell me how I can fix it so that the visitors can scroll through the webpage again?

Thanks a lot,

KR

Marek

Comment: Look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449802/html-content-only-scrolls-with-scrollbar-not-mouse-wheel

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
overflow:visible !important;
```